# Syntax highlighting in org-mode. List of languages?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

When I try to highlight SQL code in org-mode, the highlighting fails:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC SQL
SELECT *
FROM Production.Product
ORDER BY Name ASC;
#+END_SRC SQL
```

It works great for Python, shell etc, but not for SQL. I wonder if I am using the wrong keyword.

Given this:

- How can I highlight SQL code?
- Where can I find the list of languages supported?

Comment: You can find a list of supported languages in org-babel here: http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages.html. However, you can use more modes for syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`SQL` should be lowercase, `sql`, and you don't need to repeat the language name on the `END_SRC` line:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sql
  SELECT *
  FROM Production.Product
  ORDER BY Name ASC;
#+END_SRC
```

org-mode just appends `-mode` to the language name given and tries to find a major mode function.  Emacs Lisp function names are case sensitive, so `sql-mode` exists while `SQL-mode` doesn't.

You can get a list of all such functions by typing <kbd>C-h</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> `-mode$`, i.e. search for all functions that end with `-mode`, but the resulting list contains many modes that are not major modes for programming languages.

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to tell `org-mode` that `sql-mode` should be used for `SQL` snippets. This can be done with the variable `org-src-lang-modes`:

```
(add-to-list 'org-src-lang-modes (cons "SQL" 'sql))
```

For example, this kind of linking is enabled by default for `C` (`c-mode`) and `C++` / `c++` (`cpp-mode`).